# (WordPress)Trying to implement jquery to my CPT plugin script

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

First of I am bit new on developping wordpress plugins so sorry if dint find the right answer for it checked many things but cant get it to work.

So far I am trying to implement a jQuery to my wordpress plugin.

I have tried it within the html script and than load the jQuery alert to check if that works. And it do also done little of code for adding fields. But now I want to keep my code clean so that the code stays in there own code file. But that last part it doesn't work.

```html
forms.htm.php
----

<div class="bk-cpt-fields"> <!-- Create the BK CPT meta box -->
  <!-- Create the BK CPT coach name meta box -->
  <div class="coach-name"> 
    <label for="Coach_name">Coach naam </label>
    <input id="coach_name" name="coach_name" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'coach_name', TRUE)) ?>">
  </div>
  <!-- Ends the BK CPT coach name meta box -->

  <!-- Create the BK CPT coach location meta box -->
  <div class="coach_loaction">
    <table class="coach_location" id="dynamic-locations">
      <label for="coach_location">Coach locatie </label>
      <tr><input id="coach_location" name="coach_location" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'coach_location', TRUE)) ?>"></tr>
      <tr><input type="button" name="add_location" id="add_location" value="add location"></tr>
      <!-- <button name="add" id="add">Add location</button> -->
    </table>
  </div>
  <!-- Ends the BK CPT coach name meta box -->

  <!-- Create the BK CPT coach image meta box -->
  <div class="coach_image">
    <label for="coach_image"> Foto </label>
    <input id="coach_image" name="coach_image" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'coach_image', TRUE)) ?>">
  </div>
  <!-- Ends the BK CPT coach name meta box -->
</div> <!-- Ends the BK CPT meta box -->

<!-- Start loading the Jquery script for managing the forms -->
```

thats the html i got now. I have also try doing with  
But that whas resulting in console errors.

```
index.php
---------


/**
 * @file
 * create custom post type.
 */
function custom_post_type () {
  // Set UI labels for Custom Post Type:
  $labels = array(

      'name'                => _x( 'Coaches', 'Post Type General Name', 'gardener' ),
      'singular_name'       => _x( 'Coaches', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'gardener' ),
      'menu_name'           => __( 'Coaches', 'gardener' ),
      //'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Movie', 'gardener' ),
      'all_items'           => __( 'Alle Coaches', 'gardener' ),
      'view_item'           => __( 'Bekijk de Coaches', 'gardener' ),
      'add_new_item'        => __( 'Voeg een nieuwe Coach toe', 'gardener' ),
      'add_new'             => __( 'Voeg een nieuwe Coach toe', 'gardener' ),
      'edit_item'           => __( 'Bewerk de Coaches', 'gardener' ),
      'update_item'         => __( 'Update de Coaches', 'gardener' ),
      'search_items'        => __( 'Zoek een Coaches', 'gardener' ),
      'not_found'           => __( 'Niet Gevonden', 'gardener' ),
      'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Niet Gevonden in Prullenbak', 'gardener' ),
  );
  // Set other options for Custom Post Type:
  $args = array(
      'label'               => __( 'Coaches', 'gardener' ),
      'description'         => __( 'Essentiële Coaches en Eigenschappen', 'gardener' ),
      'labels'              => $labels,
      // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
      'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', ),
      // You can associate this CPT with a taxonomy or custom taxonomy. 
      'taxonomies'          => array( 'taxonomies_coach_location'),
      /**
       * A hierarchical CPT is like Pages and can have Parent and child items.
       * A non-hierarchical CPT is like Posts.
       **/ 
      'hierarchical'        => true,
      'public'              => true,
      'show_ui'             => true,
      'show_in_menu'        => true,
      'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
      'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
      'menu_position'       => 4,
      'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-palmtree',
    // dashicons-palmtree, icofont-flora
    // nametag, heart, products, award, carrot, palmtree
      'can_export'          => true,
      'has_archive'         => true,
      'exclude_from_search' => false,
      'publicly_queryable'  => true,
      'capability_type'     => 'page',
      'rewrite'             => array(
                            'slug' => 'Coaches'
    )
  );
  // Registering the Custom Post Type:
  register_post_type( 'Coaches', $args );
}

add_action('init' , 'custom_post_type');


/**
 * @file
 * This function whil register the new meta fields for the CPT.
 */
function coaches_cpt_regions_checkbox () {

  // This whil get the array for the fields
   $screens = ['Coaches', 'custom_post_type'];

  //  Here it loops trough the array and sets the wordpress meta names.
   foreach ($screens as $screen) {
       add_meta_box(
           'regio_box_id',           // Unique ID
           'Selecteer regio',  // Box title
           'coaches_cpt_regions_checkbox_html',  // Content callback, must be of type callable
           $screen                   // Post type
       );
   }
}

// Start wordpress metabox action.
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'coaches_cpt_regions_checkbox', 0);

function my_admin_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'bk-forms-js', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'js/forms.js' , array("jquery"), "1.12.4", true );
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts' );

/**
 * @file
 * Gets the forms template.
 */
function coaches_cpt_regions_checkbox_html ($post) {
  include plugin_dir_path ( __FILE__ ) . '/forms.htm.php';
}

/**
 * @file
 * This function whil save the values in the form fields.
 */
function save_coach_data_postdata ($post_id) {
  if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
    return;
  }
  if ( $parent_id = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
    $post_id = $parent_id;
  }
  $field_list = array(
    'coach_name',
    'coach_location',
    'coach_image',
  );
  foreach ($field_list as $field_name) {
    if (array_key_exists( $field_name , $_POST )) {
      update_post_meta(
        $post_id,
        $field_name,
        sanitize_text_field( $_POST[$field_name])
      );
    }
  }
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_coach_data_postdata');
```

Here i have try to do it trough couple ways of loading the script. The jQuery load is working but when i klick the add location button than it wont do anything. But when i test it outside wordpress it normaly function.

```
forms.js
------

jQuery('bk-cpt-fields').ready(function() {
  var addloactionfield = 1;

  $('#add_location').click(function() {
    addloactionfield++
    $('#dynamic_locations').append('<input id="coach_location" name="coach_location" type="text" value=""> <button name="remove" id="+addloactionfield+ class="remove-field" ">Remove location</button>');
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.remove-field', function() {
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
  });
});
```

This is the last try i done with jQuery. I have removet the jQuery alert becouse that whas working but though meby it wont continue running it. I am not that pro or junior based programmer sadly.

Already major thanks for helping!!

Greatings
   David

Comment: `jQuery('bk-cpt-fields').ready` makes little sense. Apart from that it tries to select elements by a _tag name_ that doesn’t even exist in your HTML, that is not how ready works. You need to use it in the way shown here, https://api.jquery.com/ready/, to wait for the DOM to be available, and then _inside_ of the handler function you select your elements to manipulate.

Comment: Alot thanks @misorude.

I have try to add now jQuery(document).ready(function().

Answer (score 0):

Alot thanks @misorude.

i have changed the back to document. Its stil doing nothing.
But it stil wont do much. Here i got the console error.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var addloactionfield = 1;

  $('#add_location').click(function() {
    addloactionfield++
    $('#dynamic_locations').append('<input id="coach_location" name="coach_location" type="text" value=""> <button name="remove" id="+addloactionfield+ class="remove-field" ">Remove location</button>');
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.remove-field', function() {
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
  });
});
```

```
console
------


[Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took <N>ms
post.php?post=250&action=edit:481 GET http://docker4wordpress-project.docker.localhost:8000/js/forms.js 404 (Not Found)
load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.2:8 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
post.php?post=250&action=edit:481 GET http://docker4wordpress-project.docker.localhost:8000/js/forms.js 404 (Not Found)
load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.2:2 [Violation] 'DOMContentLoaded' handler took 212ms
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 50ms
5[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking <some> event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See <URL>
tinymce.min.js?ver=4940-20190515:2 [Violation] Avoid using document.write(). https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write
rw @ tinymce.min.js?ver=4940-20190515:2
aw @ tinymce.min.js?ver=4940-20190515:2
mw @ tinymce.min.js?ver=4940-20190515:2
(anonymous) @ tinymce.min.js?ver=4940-20190515:2
(anonymous) @ tinymce.min.js?ver=4940-20190515:2
jt @ tinymce.min.js?ver=4940-20190515:2
u @ tinymce.min.js?ver=4940-20190515:2
n @ tinymce.min.js?ver=4940-20190515:2
l.<computed>.l.<computed>.l.<computed>.o.onload @ tinymce.min.js?ver=4940-20190515:2
tinymce.min.js?ver=4940-20190515:2 [Violation] 'load' handler took 403ms
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 46ms
```